# Creating Settings Screen in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm sorry if this is a simple question but I am making a button to swith between settings screen and main UI screen. I followed the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23p1vFsNvKo&t=500s pretty closely but when I click the settings button the result is rapid flickering between screens. I added the game objects in the correct places and the onclick events show the correct functions. I am stumped. Any help is much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShowSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
   //Menu States
   public enum MenuStates {Reg, Settings};
   public MenuStates currentState;
   public GameObject regScreen;
   public GameObject settingsScreen;

   //When script first starts
   void Awake()
   {
    currentState = MenuStates.Reg;
   }

   void Update()
   {
    //Checks Current State
    switch(currentState)
    {
        case MenuStates.Reg:
            //Set Active Game Objects for regular Screen
            regScreen.SetActive(true);
            settingsScreen.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case MenuStates.Settings:
            //Set Active game objects for Settings Screen
            regScreen.SetActive(false);
            settingsScreen.SetActive(true);
            break;
    }
   }

   public void OnSettings()
   {
    currentState = MenuStates.Settings;
   }
   public void OnReg()
   {
    currentState = MenuStates.Reg;
   }
}
```

Comment: I would move the code that sets the objects active to a function and call that directly from the click handler instead of doing it every frame in Update.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. I made this change and it worked right away. This is way simpler than I was making it.

Answer (score 0):

My question has been answered. For anybody curious, here is the updated code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShowSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject regScreen;
   public GameObject settingsScreen;

   //When script first starts
   void Start()
   {
        OnReg();
   }

   public void OnSettings()
   {
        settingsScreen.SetActive(true);
        regScreen.SetActive(false);
   }
   public void OnReg()
   {
        regScreen.SetActive(true);
        settingsScreen.SetActive(false);
   }
}
```